# Question about the chance of at least one packet of something being faulty

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

From a previous question, I calculated the probability of something being defective being 0.05175. Now I want to know the probability of at least one packet being faulty when someone buys 13 of them. So I was thinking that I could set is up using a binomial with $n=13$ and $p=0.05265$. Then using $P(Y\ge1)= 1-P(Y\lt1) = 1 - \binom{13}{0}*(0.05265)^{13}$ But this gives me an answer of 1 which obviously isn't right. So I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that
$$
\mathbf{P}(Y < 1) = \mathbf{P}(\text{all 13 are not faulty}) = (1 - 0.05265)^{13}
$$
since $Y < 1$ means that all 13 of them will not be faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$P(\text{some packet faulty}) = 1 - P(\text{no packets faulty}) = 1 - P(\text{packet not faulty})^{13}$$

$$P(\text{some packet faulty}) = 1 - (1 - 0.05175)^{13}\approx\boxed{0.49882}$$